# Get value name from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

how i can get "name" from array in foreach loop?

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 2
            [name] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 13
            [name] => test2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 22
            [name] => test3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [term_id] => 19
            [name] => test4
        )

)
```

i tried with foreach:

```
foreach ($tags as $get){
    $array[] = array('new' => $get[0]->name);
}
```

but not work, my question is: how to get value name from this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with -

```
foreach ($tags as $get){
    $array[] = array('new' => $get['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are very close:

```
foreach ($tags as $get){
    $array[] = array('new' => $get['name']);
}
```